# Why won't pigs spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft will not spawn any pigs in this area. It fits the required dimensions on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Monster_Spawner).

> "A monster spawner is only active when a player is within 16 blocks of it. While the block is active, it will spawn mobs within an 8x3x8 block area (8x8 wide and 3 high), centered on the corner of the spawner block with the lower x and z coordinates. Mobs can spawn anywhere in this range that is suitable, even if the immediate vicinity of the spawner block itself is not suitable."

Our area fits these dimensions exactly, why wont pigs spawn?
Picture of area:
[image]

Comment: Maybe they don't work if the area's not dark?

Comment: It is for pigs not for hostile mobs.The light level is high enough for them to spawn, also.

Comment: How do you know it's a pig spawner? All mob spawners have the pig spawner appearance in SMP, regardless of what they actually spawn.

Comment: That is one *exceptionally* well-lit room.

Comment: How would I know if it is a pig spawner or not?

Comment: Darken the room and see if hostile mobs spawn even if you're standing in it.

Comment: I thought that pigs/other animals spawned on the *highest* available point? There's a roof over this, so might that affect it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The conditions shown in your screenshot **should be able to spawn pigs**, assuming it's a pig spawner. I did a rough recreation of your setup in my world.

[image: Pig spawner.]

Even in the dark, pigs were spawning, and within seconds of placing the spawner, so it's not as if you aren't waiting long enough. (Yes, the pigs also spawned when I surrounded the spawner with Glowstone). Because of this, I have a feeling that the spawner in your image isn't actually a pig spawner; it's likely a zombie spawner, or some other hostile mob. This is especially likely if you found the spawner and it wasn't manually placed by anyone, since there wouldn't be any natural pig spawners around.

Like Kevin Reid said, you could test this by making the room dark and seeing if any hostile mobs spawn. If you have admin privileges (and don't feel like this is cheating in some sort of way), you could use `/give 52 1` to give yourself an actual pig spawner, place it in the room, and see if that one spawns pigs, just to verify if this is an odd SMP glitch that is only happening for you.

Comment: Thank you I got it working I needed to change it to a pig spawner.

Answer (score -1):

I think pigs need sky light to spawn.

Or maybe the pig spawner needs an 'minimum' Y coordinate to be.

Squids can't spawn, if you are below level 60.

Answer (score -1):

It's not spawning because the blocks should be 10x10x4 to ensure it to spawn pigs. Also it needs grass to grow on (which you already have) and it needs a minimum light level of 9 (which you also already have).

Comment: Hello, welcome to Arqade ! Though your effort to answer this question are great, you should put if you can source to support what you are saying and take care, this question is more than two years old so another answer might not be needed ^_-